# Can't delete symlink with backslash or file extension in the name - Windows/IBM/Unix PHP

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

We created test symlinks from the PHP 5.2 symlink function running on IBM i AIX (Unix) PowerSystem 5 (OS400 V7R1M0) but with backslashes or the file extension in the name (like .pdf), and are unable to delete them from our Windows boxes. (Yes, it's as crazy as it sounds)

If I try to delete or rename it from Windows (through a mapped drive to the IBM's IFS), it says "Could not find this item" but the item doesn't disappear. If I edit it with Notepad++ and type something in and save it, it creates a new file with the name as the target, and then on refresh I can delete the shortcut (symlink) but not the new file.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If you have filenames with backslashes in them on a Windows file system,
that's pretty crazy.  You have a corrupt Windows file system.

Go into Command Prompt and type `dir /x`. 
This should show you shortnames in "8.3 format";
these should not include backslashes. 
Then delete them (with the `del` command) using the shortnames.

Comment: I didn't want to mention that the developer made the symlinks that way (first time) probably due to not quite realizing the files would come out that way. It's not a corrupt Windows file system, the files are on the IBM server, created from a PHP script on the IBM server. We access them through Windows mapped drives, and the translation is handling them strangely partly due to the odd filenames. Our IBM experts were able to delete them eventually.